# Edge doesn't stretch iframe in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, iframe, flexbox, microsoft-edge

The `iframe` in the following demo is a flex item:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
iframe {
  background: olive;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

But it doesn't cover the flex container:

[image]

If you replace `iframe` with a `div`, it works with no problem.

1. Why is that?
2. What's the right approach to resolve the issue?

Comment: The `<iframe>` is flexing for me; which version of Edge are you testing?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you're seeing? [Here's what I'm seeing](http://i.imgur.com/QQZ3sUH.png).

Comment: Just added the screenshot.

Comment: What are you expecting? Are you wanting the iframe to be the full height of the root element?

Comment: Exactly - just like other browsers.

Comment: Have you tried using `vh`/`vw` units instead of flexbox?

Comment: @CBroe: It's just a sample. On my real page I have more elements and need to use a flexbox layout.

Comment: Ok, another idea for a workaround: You say when you use a `div` it works, so put the iframe into a div, position the div relative, and then the iframe inside it absolutely, setting `top/left/right/bottom` all to `0`.

Comment: @Hermes There are definitely a couple work-arounds, but this is an interop issue with Edge and Chrome/Firefox. For that reason, I will be filing a bug for the team to evaluate. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work. I started a new thread as it seems to be different from the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102990/iframe-vs-div-in-absolute-positioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does appear to be an interop issue between Microsoft Edge, and Chrome/Firefox. I'll file a bug on this immediately after answering this question, and have the team investigate further.

My immediate suggestion would be to add a `<div>` around the `<iframe>`, flex *that* `<div>`, and then set the `width` and `height` of the `<iframe>` to `100%`. [I set out to do this](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/o7bvefy1/5/), when I noticed Chrome appears to not size the iframe like Firefox and Microsoft Edge do.

I did find success with the following approach:

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://bing.com"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Flex item number 2</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
html, body, div, iframe {
  border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

Results: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/o7bvefy1/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! There's just one thing I don't understand: why do you `box-sizing: border-box;` declaration? It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I may have added that when I was adding borders during experimentation. You can strip it out :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add `min-height: 100%;` to the `iframe`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

iframe {
  background: olive;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: It might work for this simple example, but if you add other elements and containers to the page, you can't give `min-height: 100%;` to the `iframe`.

Comment: As long as the `iframe` is the only flex-item in a flex-container, the above solution works in any context as expected.

Comment: "_As long as the iframe is the only flex-item in a flex-container_" I'm afraid that's not the case in my real website.

Comment: Flex-container (with a nested `iframe` in this case) can be a flex-item itself in another flex context.