# Iframe vs. div in absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, iframe

I wonder why the following `iframe` doesn't stretch to cover the whole page:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  background: tan;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

However, a `div` stretches as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div is a **non-replaced** element. When you absolutely position it, its width is given by the CSS rules defined in [10.3.7 Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) - specifically in your case, the width is determined in step 5. Essentially the equation

> 'left' + 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' +
>   'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' +
>   'right' = width of containing block

is used where in your CSS all the values are fixed except width, so width is computed to make the equality hold.

An iframe is considered a **replaced** element. When you absolutely position it, its width is given by the CSS rules defined in [10.3.8 Absolutely positioned, replaced elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width) which defers the width calculation to the last line of the rules for [10.3.2 Inline, replaced elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) - i.e. the iframe does not have an intrinsic width, so its width is computed to be typically 300px. This is similar to the img element, which also won't expand to fill the page with the same CSS rules. But images normally do have an intrinsic width, so that width is used rather than 300px.

Similar rules apply for the height calculation.

Comment: And is it enough to use `width` and `height` only or should I use `top`, `bottom`, `right`, and `left` as well?

Comment: It's enough to use height and width to set its dimensions, yes. Note that if you set all of the values mentioned in the equation, the width is said to be *over-constrained*,  and one of the values, typically `right` will be altered to enforce the equality.

Comment: One last question, please: is it necessary to add `display:block;`? Chrome, Firefox, and Opera set the element `display` value to `block`, but Edge doesn't. I want the `iframe` to completely fill up its container available space.

Comment: I can't speak for particular implementations, but it *shouldn't* be necessary to add `display:block;` because you've used `position:absolute`, and according to the rules of [9.7 Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo), the iframe's computed display value will be `block` anyway. IE has a long history of reporting incorrect computed values for section 9.7. I've raised bugs with Microsoft myself about that.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alohci! :)

Answer (score 0):

Give `width:100%;` and `height:100;` to `iframe`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  background: tan;
  /* position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; */
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: Then why using `top`, `bottom`, `right`, and `left`. They seem to have no effect.

Comment: @Hermes It doesn't need.